# How to load a XML file in Gremlin

Tags: gremlin, gremlin-server

gremlin> graph.io(graphml()).readGraph('airroutes.xml')
airroutes.xml (The system cannot find the file specified)
Type ':help' or ':h' for help.
Display stack trace? [yN]
g=graph.traversal()

This is the error I'm getting when I'm trying to load an XML file. What is the correct way?

Comment: Did you try to use the full path of the file?

Comment: What is the syntax for full path to the file?

Answer (score 0):

Note that, and I need to update this in Practical Gremlin also, that `graph.io` is deprecated now in favor of `g.io`. If you are loading locally into an in memory TinkerGraph a simple file system path should be sufficient. If you are loading into a Gremlin Server, the server will need to have access to that file from its file system.

If loading locally, the format will look like this (I used the older `graph.io` form).

```sh
graph.io(graphml()).readGraph('/myfiles/air-routes.graphml')
```

If you are looking to load the air-routes data into a Gremlin Server, you should be able to follow [the steps here](https://kelvinlawrence.net/book/PracticalGremlin.html#servertinkergraph).